# NodeJS proper practice for route structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

over the past few days I have been researching what is the best practice for using controllers and routes in NodeJS. I wanted to split my controllers, models, middlewares and routes up instead of having a very cluttered routes page.

Finally I have came up with a working solution, I wanted your input is their a more efficient method? I feel like this seems a bit basic for now, please ask questions.

**Directory Structure**

```
MacBook-Pro:v1 MacPlusADay$ tree
.
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── controllers
│   ├── index.js
│   └── user.js
├── middlewares
├── models
├── npm-debug.log
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── style.css
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── error.jade
    ├── index.jade
    └── layout.jade
```

**app.js** I am using this method to include all of my route files into the app.js file, I feel this is easier then having to separately include each individual routes file.

```
var normalizedPath = require("path").join(__dirname, "routes");

require("fs").readdirSync(normalizedPath).forEach(function(file) {
    app.use('/', require("./routes/" + file));
});
```

**routes/index.js** I have seperated each route class with most functionality been run inside my controller classes. There can be multiple of these route files, e.g. one for users and one for posts.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var indexController = require('../controllers/index');

router.get('/', indexController.getIndex);

module.exports = router;
```

**controllers/index.js** I have separated the functionality into a module export to allow for easy editing.

```
module.exports = {
    //GET / index page
    getIndex: function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('index', { 
            title: 'Express2' 
        });
    }
};
```